# Convert DateTime Request/Response Web API core 2

Tags: api, asp.net-core, converters

I would like to build RESTful API using .NET core. Which only handles with UTC DateTime.
My purpose is: DateTime values from client (query, header, body), which will be convert to UTC before handling(before pass to Controller). I dont want to convert one by one property.

Client: post json model such as `{"createdDateTime": "2018-02-08T11:34:52.512Z"}` (Local Time)
API Server: Automatically convert Local Time to UTC and deserialize to Model. I've done by using JSONConverter and Response as well.
And Response.

But the problem is: 
I could not globally convert parameter from query URL like **www.localhost/api/order?createdDateTime=2018-02-08T11:34:52.512Z** to UTC. And Header as well.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Well I'm not sure but I think you can have custom model binder and 
```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("ClassFilter OnActionExecuting");
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
```
this filter prob you can achieve what you want

Comment: How about using `DateTimeOffset` across the whole solution?

Comment: That *is* UTC. The `Z` at the end means UTC.

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan Thanks. But It's not likes thing that I want.